# Why when I install Silverlight toolkit from nuget does not find the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals?

Tags: c#, silverlight, nuget, silverlight-toolkit, nuget-package

I've install Silverlight Toolkit from Nuget, but when I tried to run the project, it throws me one error which tells me:

> {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals, Version=4.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c5c654d367bf4a7' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals, Version=4.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c5c654d367bf4a7'}

So, I added this assembly in my project, and also is throwing me the error.

I start to think if I have to modify a nuget package or something like that.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Try to change the property SpecificVersion to false. If it does not works take a look if you have added reference paths. If the answer is yes, check if don't exists an assembly with the same name in the folder you are referencing , it must be causing a conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals.dll` is missing from the `Silverlight Toolkit Core` NuGet package. I ended up downloading the toolkit zip archive ([Silverlight releases page on CodePlex](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases)), extracting the assembly locally, and adding a reference to it to my Silverlight project. After that, all was well.

Comment: For anyone interested in Nuget support for the internals dll I just uploaded an unofficial package on [Nuget.org](https://nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkit-Internals-Unofficial/1.0.0). You can find it through the package manager by the name "SilverlightToolkit-Internals-Unofficial"

Answer (score 3):

i would suggest dont use the official nuget version for silverlight toolkit. as of writing, nuget is version 4. there are 2 newer release from official silverlight toolkit. easiest to use the binary release of dec 2011, not the recent may 2012(tricky to manually compile). silverlight toolkit sure does look abandon. unuseable and breaking release. no quickstart tutorial etc. this is based on my painful experience with the toolkit.